# Diagonalizabilty of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $2$ is the only eigen value of $A\in Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb C)$ then what can I say about the diagonalizabilty of $A$? I tried to check the equality of algebraic & geometric multiplicity of $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily conclude that **either** $A=2I_n$ **or** $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Try to prove by yourself that if $A$ is diagonalizable then $A=2I_n$, which yields the above result. If you have troubles I can give some extra hints.

Comment: $A$ is diagonalizable $\Rightarrow$ $\exists$ non-singular $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=2I$ $\Rightarrow$ $A=2I$.

Comment: @SugataAdhya Yup. So there is only one such diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So the result is actually true for any natural number.

Comment: @SugataAdhya Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing.
Even with $n=2$ you may have
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}2&0\\0&2\end{matrix}\right)$$
or 
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}2&1\\0&2\end{matrix}\right)$$